# Kernel Density Estimator (KDE) with too many zeroes as input

Tags: python, kernel-smoothing

I am using Python's seaborn package to plot a bivariate KDE. In my dataset, I have 2 columns ( A and B ) and 7000 rows. Of these 7000 rows, I have only 500 rows with values > 0. The majority of the data are 0 in both columns A and B.

As a result of this, I am facing an error/problem of dividing by zero in the KDE computation. Furthermore, if I were to only use the 500 non-zero rows I would not have that error.

Why is it that the KDE is unable to handle zeroes?

```
RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide

(1. / np.sqrt(2 * np.pi)) * np.exp(-(Xi - x)**2 / (h**2 * 2.))
```

Shouldn't the exponential term here ensure that the denominator isn't a 0?

Comment: your term h**2 can go to zero if h is zero and the exp will do nothing to that number

Comment: You are correct to say the bandwidth can go to zero. In this case, it is due to the sparsity of the dataset. @knk

Comment: You can work in the log space and convert everything back or add an infinitesimal amount so that it doesn’t go to zero